# How to get data from sever when app finished?

Tags: android

I am writing an application to parse data from my sever  ( i create sever by WAMP) and warning if the data reaches a certain threshold ( vibrate, play sound...). Therefore, i want my application still get data an warning when application finished. I know service in android can do this, but i have no idea to write a service class. So, please help me if you know.
  I have parsed data, and display it on android application. My application gets data from sever 3 minutes automaticaly.
this is code:

```
public class CurrentData extends Fragment {

public CurrentData() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

TextView id;
TextView temp;
TextView acc;
TextView moisture;
TextView battery;
TextView date;
TextView time;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.currentdata_layout,
            container, false);
    id = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.showID);
    temp = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.showTEMP);
    acc = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.showACC);
    moisture = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.showMoisture);
    battery = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.showBat);
    date = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.showDATE);
    time = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.showTIME);

    callAsynTask();
    return rootView;
}

private void callAsynTask() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynTask = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        new GetInfo().execute();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                }
            });

        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynTask,0, 180000);
}

public class GetInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Parameter> {

    @Override
    protected Parameter doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        String data = ((new LandSlideHttpClient().getDeviceData()));
        Parameter parameter = new Parameter();
        try {
            parameter = JSONLandslideParser.getParameter(data);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return parameter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Parameter result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        id.setText(result.id.getID());
        temp.setText(" " + result.currentData.getTemp());// + "  °C");
        acc.setText(" " + result.currentData.getAcc());// + "  m/s2");
        moisture.setText(" " + result.currentData.getMoisture());// +
                                                                    // "  mps");
        battery.setText(" " + result.currentData.getBattery());// + "  %");
        date.setText(result.currentData.getDate());
        time.setText(result.currentData.getTime());
        new warning(); // class to alert

    }

}
```

}

Comment: I'm sorry, but you've got to read documentation, follow couple tutorials and to try it yourself. Right now your question is too broad and doesn't fit SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create background service. If you are using android studio then it is very easy to create service. Just make sure you must have all necessary information about services and how to make then persistent in background.

Because of this your application will drain your device battery drastically. Understand each details about service life cycle.

See this link for more information

1. https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html
2. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html
3. http://javatechig.com/android/creating-a-background-service-in-android
4. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm

Comment: @datle193 check out details